# system.log main.CRITICAL( imagepng) Permission denied in/public_html/vendor/zendframework/zend-captcha/src/Image.php on line 588 []

Tags: magento2, error, system.log

this is from system.log. where should i look into to fix this problem?

```
  [2019-05-19 08:57:03] main.CRITICAL: Warning: imagepng(/home/user123/public_html/pub/media/captcha/base/6ee2xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.png): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /home/user123/public_html/vendor/zendframework/zend-captcha/src/Image.php on line 588 [] []
    [2019-05-19 08:57:04] main.CRITICAL: Warning: imagepng(/home/user123/public_html/pub/media/captcha/base/e079xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.png): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /home/user123/public_html/vendor/zendframework/zend-captcha/src/Image.php on line 588 [] []
    [2019-05-19 08:57:20] main.CRITICAL: Warning: imagepng(/home/user123/public_html/pub/media/captcha/base/ae84xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.png): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /home/user123/public_html/vendor/zendframework/zend-captcha/src/Image.php on line 588 [] []
    [2019-05-19 08:57:21] main.CRITICAL: Warning: image
```

Comment: Change the permission of pub/media directory

Comment: i believe my pub/media directory is set correct 755&664. upon checking, this 3 images file does not exist in that folder. how can i clear the error out?

Comment: something is calling those images. You are saying that those images do not exist? If that is the case it's possible that those images are cached. Try to clear the cache

Answer (score 2):

Try this commands as a root user

```
find var generated vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type f -exec chmod g+w {} + find var generated vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type d -exec chmod g+ws {} +
sudo chown -R <Magento user>:<web server group> .
```

It seems to be a permission issue only, if the image is not found there you will be getting file not found error. So try setting the permissions for existing files and newly created files using the above command and check if the issue still exists

Comment: I agree with this.  PHP is trying to write the unique CAPTCHA image but does not have the required premissions, which is why the images are not present when you look for them

Comment: sounds like this is the issue. I have encounter a lot of permission issues since the site is transferred. However, i'm still find my <web server group> name, there is no "apache" or "www-data" exist in the server.. do you have any clue? it's liquidweb centOS.

Comment: Do you use a shared server or VPS or dedicated server?

Comment: Run this you will get web user name grep -E -i '^user|^group' /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf

Comment: dedicated server. should i need to run it as root? from my cpanel account it returned no such file or directory.

Comment: You should run as root user